# Why won't my variables display? It've always worked fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

So, I've written copies of this code soo many times before and it've worked just fine but now it just dont want to display my variables! I've looked through every little thing in my working html code and literally copied the needed things to my new file, but it just don't want to work...
The "str" and "score" are supposed to show up as "Loading... 0" in the top left corner but nope, nothing...
Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Loading...</title>
 <style>
  body{
   font-size:20px;
   margin:0;
   overflow:hidden;
  }
  #str{
   display:block;
   font-size:30px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 1.0em;
   left: 1.0em;
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
  }
  #str:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  #score{
   display:block;
   font-size:30px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 2.0em;
   left: 1.0em;
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
  }
  #score:hover{
   cursor: default;
  }
  #blackBox{
   background-color:black;
   display:block;
   position:fixed;
   width:0.1%;
   bottom:4.0em;
   left:0.0em;
   padding:0.5em 0em;
   text-align:left;
   vertical-align:top;
   border:2px solid black;
  }
  #blackBox2{
   display:block;
   position:fixed;
   width:99.5%;
   bottom:4.0em;
   left:0.0em;
   padding:0.5em 0em;
   text-align:left;
   vertical-align:top;
   border:2px solid black;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-33914917-1']);
   _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'dhmholley.co.uk']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

   (function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

 </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialise()">

<div id="blackBox"></div>
<div id="blackBox2"></div>

<script>
var prc = 0,
 W = 1,

function initialise(){
 createInterface();
 updateScore();
}

function mload(){
   prc = prc + 1;
   W = prc / 100;
   document.getElementById("blackBox").style.width = W + "%";
   updateScore();
}

function createInterface(){
 var score = document.createElement('div');
 score.id = 'score';
 score.innerHTML = prc;
 document.body.appendChild(score);

 var str = document.createElement('div');
 str.id = 'str';
 str.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
 str.onclick = function(){
  mload();
 }
 document.body.appendChild(str);
}

function updateScore(){
 document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = prc;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the console? It's right there for you

Comment: var prc=0,w=1,function is a syntax error

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function"`

Comment: @Jonasw Omg, thx bro! I can't belive that was the thing. the thing that bothers me though is that my working code is written like that and theres no problem... strange

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare multiple variables with one var statement but you have to close every command with an ; ! Its possible to leave it but i wouldnt (there are good examples out there:

```
//not good but should work:
var a,b
function c(){}

//the best solution:
var a,b;
function c(){};

//what you did
var a,b,function c(){};
//wich is invalid
```